# Fullcalendar - Undo moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar to schedule events and I'm looking for a new function where the user can undo moves that been done in the calendar.

Do you guys know a smart way to do this?

The first thing that comes to my mind is to save previous states in in a new table and when the user wants to undo moves the system just reset the values in the events table with the ones in the "previous state" table.

Comment: Sounds right to me. A problem will be where you want to undo removeEvent and recreating that event with all its attributes. Maybe you can integrate with something like an [undo manager](https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager)

Comment: Thanks! I will look closer into that undo manager.:)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution for this.  It may not be the most elegant but it works for me.  I have a column in by events table called e_history; it's content is an array of JSON.stringified data that contains {date:"1/12/2012",startTime:"8:00",duration:4}.  In my system the duration value corresponds with a value that is mapped out based on 30 minute time increments.  In my event pop ups ($.dialog) I have a button the user can click to see old schedule dates - that are clickable if they want to set the event back to an old date.  This only works for monitoring individual events.  If you want to remember the entire state of the calendar, you could just save a stringified copy of the events object.  This would allow the flexibility to parse it as needed and monitor differences from your db.